# CURDATE() is not valid at this position expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql

### MYSQL

```
create table Emp
( 
 Eid int primary key,
 Ename varcharacter(20) not null,
 Eage int,
 Eadd varcharacter(21) default ' Cairo ',
 HireDate date DEFAULT  ***CURDATE( )***,
 
);
```

I want to set a default value in the hiring date to be the current date if no date is written in the column but  nothing works `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURDATE()`

Comment: You have a couple of typos in your code; check the documentation for the correct `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it  .. what is the documentation for the correct CREATE TABLE syntax?

Comment: Also, see this: [MySQL error - creating table and trying current date as default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75974335/mysql-error-creating-table-and-trying-current-date-as-default/75974754#75974754)

Comment: " ( " is not valid at this Position ... the same error  when tying any of those syntaxes (CURDATE())   or  (CURRENT_DATE())  or (CURRENT_DATE)

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Probably just missing parentheses around the expression:

```
HireDate date DEFAULT (CURDATE( )),
```

Comment: " ( " is not valid at this Position